# HTML page and button text auto wrapping - cross-browser support required

Tags: html

I'm looking for a cross-browser supported way to wrap a button text.

How well does the browsers support the following code? I mean, will they auto-wrap the text if button text width is more than 100px?

Mozilla Firefox seems to wrap the text nicely.

```html
<table style="width: 100px">
<tr>
<td><button>a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Or should I use this code instead?

```html
<table style="width: 100px">
<tr>
<td><button>a a a a a a<br />a a a a a a<br />a a a a a a<br />a a</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have spaces between the characters, that should wrap neatly in all browsers no problem. The issue you'll have arises when you have words there like 'pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis.' Because there's no spaces, the browser will have no clue where to start line breaks and manually inserting `<br>` tags will lead to some pretty unmaintainable code.

Checkout out the link I've posted below. It's got some good tips on wrapping text or truncating it. My favorite trick is to use the following css to enforce truncation:

```
   text-overflow: ellipsis;

   /* Required for text-overflow to do anything */
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
```

And then give a `title` property to your button that has all of your text. When a user hovers, it will read out all of your text.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/